# How to build the gridview from 2 tables and save co-ordinates mapping in 3'rd table in asp.net web form?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, many-to-many

I am having Component table, Role table, and ComponentRoleMapping table in database. Please look at the image below. I want to populate the column Component names as first column filled with all rows and roles should be the first row of grid from Role table. All cell have to have check box. The matrix co-ordinate have to save that coordination in ComponentRoleMapping table by clicking on any check box. In short to populate many to many relationship among components and Roles I need this view. I am using asp.net web form and gridview control to populate this. how to populate single gridview from 2 tables / datatables ? Or any other control I can use here. Or any article I can follow for exact purpose?

[image]

Comment: any guidelines please. Is my question wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a RoleComponent table which is a simple table of pk's that maps a Component to a Role.  Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoleComponent](
    [role_pk] [int] NOT NULL,
    [component_pk] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A checkbox is initially checked if an entry in this table exists for a specific role and component.

When a user:

- Checks a checkbox: insert a row for the given role_pk and component_pk
- UnCheck a checkbox: delete a row for the given role_pk and component_pk

To get the grid of checkboxes as you have in your display you are going to need to return a pivot table of bit fields.  Pivot tables are not simple in SqlServer.  In fact they are downright annoying.

A Repeater might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I am more curious about to populate the gridview that shown in fact. Where as the suggestion for RoleComponent always be helpful.

Comment: I told you how. You have to create and return, to the gridview,  a pivot table of bit fields from sqlserver.  Essentially rows of ones and zeros where a 1 represents an entry into the mapping table. once you have that then you bind just bind a gridview of checkbox fields to the returnd rows.  A Formview may be a better option because you can have the FormView default to edit mode where the checkboxes will be clickable.

Comment: Thanks, any reference link with similar  implementation ?

Comment: Unfortunately no - best I can offer is a methodology.  You can look up implementing custom membership and role providers using .Net.  What your are trying to accomplish is called a membership/role pattern.  it's common for inventory management, menu systems, user account membership, etc.  any situation where you have to have groups of items belonging to other groups of items you'll recognize a form of its implementation

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, It might helpful to others. Rather to use Grid control I used Html table only.
Here Dt1 has Components, Dt2 has Roles and Dt3 used for to check active status. May be some dead code in this but, running perfect.

```
Private Sub GenerateTable(dt2 As DataTable, dt1 As DataTable, dt3 As DataTable)

        Dim table As New Table()
        Dim row As TableRow = Nothing    
        'Add the Headers
        row = New TableRow()            
        'Empty 
        Dim headerCellEmpty As New TableHeaderCell()
        headerCellEmpty.Text = ""
        headerCellEmpty.Attributes("style") = "border:1px solid black;text-align:center;"
        row.Cells.Add(headerCellEmpty)    
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim headerCell As New TableHeaderCell()
            headerCell.Text = dt2.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            headerCell.ID = dt2.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            'Check All Components
            Dim chkAllComponent As New CheckBox()
            chkAllComponent.ID = "allcomponents_" + dt2.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            chkAllComponent.Text = dt2.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            headerCell.Controls.Add(chkAllComponent)

            headerCell.Attributes("style") = "border:1px solid black;text-align:center;width:15%;"
            row.Cells.Add(headerCell)
        Next
        table.Rows.Add(row)

        'Add the Column values
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            row = New TableRow()
            For j As Integer = 0 To dt1.Columns.Count - 2
                Dim cell As New TableCell()
                cell.Text = dt1.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
                cell.ID = dt1.Rows(i)(j + 1).ToString()
                'Check All Roles
                Dim chkAllRoles As New CheckBox()
                chkAllRoles.ID = "allroles_" + dt1.Rows(i)(j + 1).ToString()
                chkAllRoles.Text = dt1.Rows(i)(j).ToString()
                cell.Controls.Add(chkAllRoles)

                row.Cells.Add(cell)
            Next

            ' Add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If table.Rows(0).Cells.Count > 0 Then


                'Add check boxes
                Dim allColumnsCountinTable As Integer = table.Rows(0).Cells.Count
                For Each tr As TableRow In table.Rows
                    Dim rowIndex As Integer = table.Rows.GetRowIndex(tr)
                    If rowIndex = 0 Then
                    Else
                        For f As Integer = 1 To allColumnsCountinTable - 1
                            Dim cell As New TableCell()
                            Dim roleid = table.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(0).ID
                            Dim roleId1 As Guid = New Guid(roleid)
                            Dim componentid = table.Rows(0).Cells(f).ID
                            Dim Check1 As New CheckBox()
                            Check1.ID = "chk_" + roleid + "_" + componentid


                            Dim configurations = From p In dt3.AsEnumerable() Select p

                            If (configurations.Any(Function(coffee) c.Field(Of Integer)("ComponentId") = componentid And c.Field(Of Guid)("RoleId") = roleId1)) Then

                                Dim isActive = configurations.Where(Function(coffee) c.Field(Of Integer)("ComponentId") = componentid And c.Field(Of Guid)("RoleId") = roleId1).FirstOrDefault()("IsActive")
                                If isActive = True Then
                                    Check1.Checked = True
                                Else
                                    Check1.Checked = False
                                End If
                            Else
                                Check1.Checked = False
                            End If
                            Check1.Attributes("Name") = "checkbox"
                            cell.Attributes("style") = "border:1px solid black;text-align:center;"
                            cell.Controls.Add(Check1)
                            tr.Cells.AddAt(f, cell)
                        Next
                    End If
                    tr.Attributes("style") = "color:red; border:1px solid black;"
                Next
            End If
        End If

        'Styling


            Panel1.Controls.Add(table)

    End Sub
```